# IE8 embedded font dissapears on refresh

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, refresh, font-face

I am using an embedded font via `@font-face` and it works fine... **until** on IE8 (Haven't tried on newer versions) when you do something crazy like refresh or use the backward and forward buttons to reload the page.

What's even worse is that it doesn't even default to a font in my font stack, it appears to go straight to Arial (with some serious spacing issues).

A live example can be seen here:

http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/

An image comparison for your viewing pleasure:

[image: Image comparison]

The relevant CSS for your perusing pleasure:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DroidSerifRegular';
    src: url('DroidSerif-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('DroidSerif-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('DroidSerif-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('DroidSerif-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('DroidSerif-Regular-webfont.svg#DroidSerifRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

**An interesting note:**

Somehow [Google web fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts/) appears to be immune to this issue. Which gives me faith that although this may be a browser bug, there is definitely a work-around.

Incase your wondering why I don't just use their service; I can't.

Comment: I can't repro with IE8 on Windows Server 2003.

Comment: @thirtydot Thanks for the info, I am on XP. It isn't just me as I've found related questions online. Just no solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use Google fonts, then maybe a different solution of your problem. See CUFON library [here](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/).
It converts regular TTF font to javascript file, which you download and embed in your HTML code, then  particular DOM elements (by your choice) are replaced with `canvas` tags.

Comment: Thanks budiony, I used to use CUFON but I don't like the way it is invisibly selected.

Comment: What do you mean by "invisibly selected"?

Comment: You can highlight text, but you can't see the highlight.